# How many ways can choose 3 numbers to form a decreasing sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose we have the set A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. How many ways can
choose 3 numbers to form a decreasing sequence? (Hint: < 6, 4, 4 > is decreasing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3$ possibilities:

All three numbers are the same, there are $7$ ways to do this.

Two numbers are equal and the third is different, there are $7 \times 6 $ ways to do this.

All three numbers are different, there are $ 7 \times 6 \times 5/3!$ ways to do this.

So there are $7+42+35=\color{red}{84}$ ways.

Comment: Why is it not $7\choose 3$ in the third case?

Comment: @Idle You are right, I had over counted in the third case.

Comment: yes i have trouble of understanding at the begining, the op is less articulate.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a not-necessarily-strictly decreasing sequence $\langle x, y, z \rangle$ such that $7 \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq 1$ is the same as choosing a strictly decreasing sequence $\langle x + 2, y + 1, z \rangle$ such that $9 \geq x + 2 > y + 1 > z \geq 1$. This amounts to choosing 3 distinct values from a set of size 9. Thus, the number of ways it can be done is $\binom{9}{3} = 84$.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the familiar "stars and bars" paradigm with $3$ identical balls and $7$ labelled bins.

There would be $\binom{3+7-1}{7-1} = 84$ results, with occupied bins defining the number, e.g.

$\;7\quad |\;6\quad |\;5\quad |\;4\quad |\;3\quad |\;2\quad |\;1\;\;$ corresponding to $775$
$\circ\circ\quad\quad\quad\circ$

Answer (score 1):

The boring method... open to anyone willing to do the work.

```
77X - 7 options for X
76X - 6 options 
:   down to
71X - 1 option 
& so...
---> 7XY -- 28 options 
---> 6XY -- 21 options
---> 5XY -- 15 options
---> 4XY -- 10 options
---> 3XY --  6 options
---> 2XY --  3 options
---> 1XY --  1 option
```

$\to 28+21+15+10+6+3+1 =84 $ options.